# Hide a particular radio box item in a set

Tags: 7

I want to hide a particular item from an entity field that is using a radio box as widget. Can I achieve this using `hook_form_alter()`?

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by disable? do you want it to show and not be editable or do you want to hide it from certain/all users? there are many solutions but need to know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @longboardnode I need to hide it specifically

Comment: you could hide it with a module by role, you can hide it completely with node content settings, you can hide it with css... so many options you gotta give some direction here

Answer (score 0):

To remove the entire field on the form, you can definitely do something like this

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == "form_id_for_form_you_want_to_modify") {
    if (isset($form["field_you_want_to_remove"])) {
      unset($form["field_you_want_to_remove"]);
    }

  }

  return $form;
}
```

To change or remove a specific option on the field you can access and alter it with $form['field_your_field']['und']['#options']

(note: If your site is multilingual, you'll need to alter more than just ['und']. In this case ['und'] means undefined language code).

You can also alter the field type with:

```
$form['field_your_field']['#type'] = 'checkboxes';
```

It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.